# apache rewrite rule for http_host containing port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In the local network, I have synology server with a number of services running in docker on different ports and accessible in-browser like that
`192.168.1.2:8989` or `server.spb.lan:8989`

How to make a rewrite rule to convert them like that `192.168.1.2/servicename` or `server.spb.lan/servicename`?

Like that

```
192.168.1.2:8989     ->  192.168.1.2/servicename
server.spb.lan:8989  ->  server.spb.lan/servicename
```

Comment: Could you please post example of urls like from which url to which url you want to convert please for better understanding of question.

Comment: I supposed it is clearly written in the question. But anyway I added that above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the issue with apache installed directly on Synology. So I deleted it, deleted web station. Then I install nginx in docker. Synology has integrated nginx running on port 80, which cannot be deleted and there is no access to its settings.
So I just mapped internal port 80 of nginx container to port 82 on Synology, make forward port 80 from router to port 82 on Synology.
And then in config of nginx container I did simply that for each of my app running in docker

```
server {
    server_name sonarr.lan;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8989;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache after placing these rules in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 192\.168\.1\.2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/servicename [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8989%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} server\.spb\.lan
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/servicename [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8989%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```

Comment: I delete all browser history including apsswords, cookies and all options, but your solution is not working. I forgot to mention that these services, which at the moment available only using IP:PORT syntax are running in docker containers. So they don't have htaccess files. The only thing I have - each docker app has port exposed to the server. So I have only possibility to add virtualhost.conf file and add your code into conf file.

Comment: @schel4ok, ohhhh this was not mentioned in question and it changed it a lot now, I am not sure on docker, will check it and get back to you if I get something on this one.

Comment: But when I execute  `netstat -lntp` on 192.168.1.2 main machine I see that port
`tcp6       0      0 :::8989                 :::*                    LISTEN      9118/docker-proxy`
So I suppose it should be visible to apache running on this machine

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` directives would seem to be missing the first argument (_pattern_). However, you can't _internally rewrite_ the request from one port to another. The above would implicitly trigger an external (302) redirect. If the underlying ports cannot be changed then you would need to implement a reverse proxy as an additional service in front of these docker services. (?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that those backend services operate based on the http protocol, since you did not specify anything else...

Easiest probably is to use the apache proxy module to expose those backend services. You can use it within the rewriting module which makes the approach pretty convenient:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?servicename(/.*)$ https://server.spb.lan:8989$1 [P]
```

An alternative to the rewriting module would be to implement a reverse proxy:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /servicename https://server.spb.lan:8989
ProxyPassReverse /servicename https://server.spb.lan:8989
```

I suggest you read about the details in the apache documentation. As typical for OpenSource it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples.